# InotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: design-patterns, inotifypropertychanged

I have an interface called IMailSender and ISMSSender.
I have an abstract class called Device.

Device1 inherits from Device, IMailSender
Device2 inherits from Device, IMailSender, ISMSSender

I want all fields of IMailSender to call notifypropertychanged.
Do I have to implement also in Device1 all the IMailSender properties to call notifypropertychanged and to do the same code in Device2 or there is better solution ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your class must raise the `PropertyChanged` event as the interface will only ensure that all implementing classes have a method with the same return type. A good approach would be to define a base class (this is a very common approach with the MVVM pattern e.g. MVVM Light framework) that raises the event through a method, from which all other appropriate classes can inherit. E.g:

```
...
public abstract class BaseViewModel : IMailSender, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ...
    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (property != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(property);
        }
    }
}
```

An inheriting class could use this as follows:

```
...
public class AViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    ...
    private string _property;
    public string Property
    {
        get
        {
            return _property;
        }
        set
        {
            _property = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Property");
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An other solution would be Aspect Orientied. For example with postsharp.
s. http://www.sharpcrafters.com/solutions/notifypropertychanged

So you can place a PropertyChanged Attribute on the property.

Also with .net 4.5 you can use the CallerInfoAttribute to make an easy implementation which doesn't need the propertyname for example see:

http://danrigby.com/2012/04/01/inotifypropertychanged-the-net-4-5-way-revisited/
->

```
 protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var eventHandler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (eventHandler != null)
        {
            eventHandler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

with that you can call the method without any parametr

```
public int MyProperty
{
  get
   {
   ...
   }

    set
    {
        m_MyProperty=value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this, call ObservableFactory.Create() and use the return object. To use the notify event just cast it to INotifyPropertyChanged

```
    public static class ObservableFactory
    {
        public static T Create<T>(T target)
        {
            if (!typeof(T).IsInterface)
                throw new ArgumentException("Target should be an interface", "target");

            var proxy = new Observable<T>(target);
            return (T)proxy.GetTransparentProxy();
        }
    }

    internal class Observable<T> : RealProxy, INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyPropertyChanging
    {
        private readonly T target;

        internal Observable(T target)
            : base(ImplementINotify(typeof(T)))
        {
            this.target = target;
        }

        public override IMessage Invoke(IMessage msg)
        {
            var methodCall = msg as IMethodCallMessage;

            if (methodCall != null)
            {
                return HandleMethodCall(methodCall);
            }

            return null;
        }

        public event PropertyChangingEventHandler PropertyChanging;
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;



        IMessage HandleMethodCall(IMethodCallMessage methodCall)
        {
            var isPropertySetterCall = methodCall.MethodName.StartsWith("set_");
            var propertyName = isPropertySetterCall ? methodCall.MethodName.Substring(4) : null;

            if (isPropertySetterCall)
            {
                OnPropertyChanging(propertyName);
            }

            try
            {
                object methodCalltarget = target;

                if (methodCall.MethodName == "add_PropertyChanged" || methodCall.MethodName == "remove_PropertyChanged"||
                    methodCall.MethodName == "add_PropertyChanging" || methodCall.MethodName == "remove_PropertyChanging")
                {
                    methodCalltarget = this;
                }

                var result = methodCall.MethodBase.Invoke(methodCalltarget, methodCall.InArgs);

                if (isPropertySetterCall)
                {
                    OnPropertyChanged(methodCall.MethodName.Substring(4));
                }

                return new ReturnMessage(result, null, 0, methodCall.LogicalCallContext, methodCall);
            }
            catch (TargetInvocationException invocationException)
            {
                var exception = invocationException.InnerException;
                return new ReturnMessage(exception, methodCall);
            }
        }

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanging(string propertyName)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanging;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangingEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public static Type ImplementINotify(Type objectType)
        {
            var tempAssemblyName = new AssemblyName(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());

            var dynamicAssembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(
                tempAssemblyName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndCollect);

            var moduleBuilder = dynamicAssembly.DefineDynamicModule(
                tempAssemblyName.Name,
                tempAssemblyName + ".dll");

            var typeBuilder = moduleBuilder.DefineType(
                objectType.FullName, TypeAttributes.Public | TypeAttributes.Interface | TypeAttributes.Abstract);

            typeBuilder.AddInterfaceImplementation(objectType);
            typeBuilder.AddInterfaceImplementation(typeof(INotifyPropertyChanged));
            typeBuilder.AddInterfaceImplementation(typeof(INotifyPropertyChanging));
            var newType = typeBuilder.CreateType();
            return newType;
        }
    }
```